# Cannot see notification sent with firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a mobile device that is registering with topic using `FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic("newTopic")`

I am using **OAuth 2.0 Playground** to get an access token. I am sending a POST request as follows but not seeing any notifcation on the device registered to that topic. The CURL request returns a status code of 200 OK.

```
curl -X POST -k -H 'Authorization: Bearer access_token_goes_here' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -i 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/projectId/messages:send' --data '{
  "message":{
    "topic" : "newTopic",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is a Firebase Cloud Messaging Topic Message!",
      "title" : "FCM Message"
      }
   }
}
```

Just to know if im receiving the notification, im handling the notification as follows:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print('Got a message whilst in the foreground!');
      print('Message data: ${message.data}');

      if (message.notification != null) {
        print('Message also contained a notification: ${message.notification}');
      }
    });
```

Comment: Android or iOS or both?

Comment: Both on Android and iOS

Comment: Remember that Notification messages which arrive while the application is in the foreground will not display a visible notification by default: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/receive#foreground_messages.

Comment: @user18309290, check the edit, i tried it but still nothing

Answer (score 2):

```
Initial notification configuration:
await Firebase.initializeApp();
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterNotificationPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
const AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
  'channel ID',
  'channel name',
  playSound: true,
  importance: Importance.max,
);
await flutterNotificationPlugin
    .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
        AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
    ?.createNotificationChannel(channel);
var initializationSettingsAndroid =
    const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
var initializationSettingsIOS = const DarwinInitializationSettings();
var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
    android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
await flutterNotificationPlugin.initialize(
  initializationSettings,
);
```

//LocalNotification show

```
FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
if (!kIsWeb) {
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance
      .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );
}
 FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
    RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
    //AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
    if (notification != null) {
      log("On message: $notification");
      log(message.data.toString());

      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
        FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin().show(
            0, notification.title, notification.body, notificationDetails);
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).